# UIView breaking in iOS7 but not in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, nslayoutconstraint

I have created a custom view to show 2 labels inside a circle. It is suppose to look like this:
[image: Looking correctly]

but in iOS 7 it looks like this:
[image: Looking wrong]

That happens because the constraints hat are supposed to stick the labels to the top/bottom are breaking for some reason, but only on iOS 7. I get the following error:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f96e500a540 H:|-(-1)-[UILabel:0x7f96e2dd84d0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f96e2df6350 )>" )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint  <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f96e500a540 H:|-(-1)-[UILabel:0x7f96e2dd84d0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f96e2df6350 )>
```

I have confirmed that those are in fact the constraints called (I only gave one error as an example)

```
self.dayLabelStickButtomConstraint
self.monthLabelStickTopConstraint
```

Here is the code for the custom view, can anyone maybe understand why is it breaking on iOS 7 but not on 8?

```
- (instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initiateValues];
        [self buildHeirarchy];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initiateValues];
        [self buildHeirarchy];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)initiateValues{
    self.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    self.month = @"jan";
    self.monthFontSize = 8.0f;
    self.monthTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.monthLabelInsetDistance = 1.0f;

    self.day = @"01";
    self.dayFontSize = 12.0f;
    self.dayTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.dayLabelInsetDistance = 1.0f;
}

-(void)buildHeirarchy{
    self.innerContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.bounds, 5.0, 5.0)];
    [self.innerContainer setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self addSubview:self.innerContainer];
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.innerContainer
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                      constant:0.0]];
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.innerContainer
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                      constant:0.0]];
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.innerContainer
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                    multiplier:0.7
                                                      constant:0.0]];
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.innerContainer
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                    multiplier:0.7
                                                      constant:0.0]];


    self.monthLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.bounds, 5.0, 5.0)];
    [self.monthLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    self.monthLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.innerContainer addSubview:self.monthLabel];

    [self.innerContainer addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.monthLabel
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:self.innerContainer
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                                     constant:0.0]];

    NSLayoutConstraint *monthTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.monthLabel
                                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTopMargin
                                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                             toItem:self.innerContainer
                                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTopMargin
                                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                                           constant:self.monthLabelInsetDistance];
    self.monthLabelStickTopConstraint = monthTopConstraint;
    [self.innerContainer addConstraint:self.monthLabelStickTopConstraint];


    self.dayLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.bounds, 5.0, 5.0)];
    [self.dayLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.innerContainer addSubview:self.dayLabel];
    self.dayLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    [self.innerContainer addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.dayLabel
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:self.innerContainer
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                                     constant:0.0]];

    NSLayoutConstraint *dayButtomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.dayLabel
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottomMargin
                                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                              toItem:self.innerContainer
                                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottomMargin
                                                                          multiplier:1.0
                                                                            constant:self.dayLabelInsetDistance];

    self.dayLabelStickButtomConstraint = dayButtomConstraint;
    [self.innerContainer addConstraint:self.dayLabelStickButtomConstraint];



}

-(void)layoutSubviews{
    // get the graphics context
    if (!self.backgroundColorRoundView) {

        self.backgroundColorRoundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        [self addSubview:self.backgroundColorRoundView];
        [self sendSubviewToBack:self.backgroundColorRoundView];
        self.backgroundColorRoundLayer = [CAShapeLayer new];
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.backgroundColorRoundView.bounds];
        self.backgroundColorRoundLayer.path = path.CGPath;
        //imageMaskLayer.fillColor = self.fillColor.CGColor;
        [self.backgroundColorRoundView.layer addSublayer:self.backgroundColorRoundLayer];
    }
    self.backgroundColorRoundView.frame = self.bounds;
    self.backgroundColorRoundLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    [self updateViews];
    [super layoutSubviews];

}

-(void)updateViews{
    self.monthLabel.textColor = self.monthTextColor;
    self.dayLabel.textColor = self.dayTextColor;
    self.backgroundColorRoundLayer.fillColor = self.fillColor.CGColor;
}

-(void)updateConstraints{
    self.dayLabelStickButtomConstraint.constant = self.dayLabelInsetDistance;
    self.monthLabelStickTopConstraint.constant = self.monthLabelInsetDistance;

    [super updateConstraints];

}
```

Comment: Did you try setting autoresizing mask before you apply constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of messing around the answer lied in the restraints themselves. Once i switched from topMargin,bottomMargin to just top and bottom it worked